# 401k plan vs company size

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k, retirement-plan

I am looking for financial information about a private company. All I could find that is publicly disclosed is the 401k plan details (form 5500)

The form mentions a plan net asset of $1.5M, 19 participants for an average account balance of $79k

From this information, can I make assumptions about the gross revenue of the company? Net income? Anything else? I am trying to understand if this is a $10M company or more of a $40-50M (obviously not expecting exact numbers)

Lots of thanks

**EDIT:** among the 19 401k participants, 14 are active, 5 are not. Let’s say I estimate the company has about 15-20 employees currently. It is a software company with about 30years of existence and a market leader in its field. Licenses range between $1000 and $7500 a year with a 50% discount after the first year. Assuming they have a *pretty good* cost of sale ratio, what would be an average range for companies satisfying these criteria? And for a *top* one? I know it could be anything but trying to get a feel...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Is this related to your personal finances in any way?

Comment: This tells you more about the employees than the company - as the annual contribution limit is 18k, the "average" employee participant has worked for at 4 years, if they're maximizer types and paid well enough to max out.  Or longer if they are not.  They may have rolled over from a prior employer.

Answer (score 6):

No.

There are too many things that we don't know.

19 plan members. Is this the full employment number for company, or do they have such a bad plan, it's 19 out of 100?

Does the company even have sales? A drug start up may have employees, paid, but no product for sale yet, just research and hope.

A manufacturing company might have a low sales per employee ratio, vs a software company whose cost of sales is mostly wages.

I could go on, but you get the idea.

Comment: Do you think the edit could help get a better picture?

Comment: Not really. Software, as I suggested, can have a huge sales/employee ratio. Where would one even begin to guess what the sales number is from just knowing the number working there?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make some very general guesses about the size of the company, but they would be guesses.

If there are 19 participants in the 401k plan, then the company must have had at least 19 employees over it's lifetime. But that doesn't tell you much. They could have a very high turnover, 19 employees each working for the company for 1 year for the past 19 years and now have just one employee, or all 19 could still be working for the company now. Even if all 19 are currently working for the company, you have no way of knowing if every employee is in the 401k, so they have a total of 19 employees, or if for some reason most employees don't participate in the 401k -- maybe it isn't very good, or they just started it last year, or most of the employees are young and haven't bothered to start saving for retirement, etc, etc -- and so its 19 out of 1000.

Realistically, I'd guess that this company probably has 10 to 100 employees. It's unlikely that they have 40,000 employees but on 19 are in the 401k. But that's about as much as one could say.